# How to Create Drawer menu without Navigation?

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, drawer

I am looking to create  a drawer, similar to a drawer navigator, but without the routes/navigation requirement.

I plan on placing some other components there that update a query. Any recommendations? Specifically the drawer would be used to display picklists, sliders, and date range components that would update the state and variables used in updating markers rendered on a map shown on the home page.

Comment: What would be the exact use case of the separate drawer?

Comment: Picklist, Slider, Date Range components that would update the state and variables used in updating markers rendered on a map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### With Redux

You can use the `contentComponent` of the [createDrawerNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-navigator.html) to create your own custom drawer and bind it to `redux-store`.

By dispatching the **actions** with relevant queries you can update the variables as they are passed from the store to your Component.

### Without Redux

You can either create a **CustomDrawer** component with similar animation and render it in your Component or use this [`react-native-drawer`](https://github.com/root-two/react-native-drawer).

```
import Drawer from 'react-native-drawer'

class Application extends Component {  
  closeControlPanel = () => {
    this._drawer.close()
  };
  openControlPanel = () => {
    this._drawer.open()
  };
  render () {
    return (
      <Drawer
        ref={(ref) => this._drawer = ref}
        content={<DrawerContentComponent {...// Your Updater props}/>}
        >
        <Component />
      </Drawer>
    )
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually ended up going with React Native Side Menu due to the recommendation from the react-native-drawer git. Link for anyone else: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-side-menu